# 'HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'GetElementById'

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, win-universal-app

I'm trying to download a webpage and trying to extract some specific data in Windows Universal Apps. I'm using  **HtmlAgilityPack** I wrote following code segment. But I'm having some error.

```
    async public void LoadDataFromWeb()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient(); // Add: using System.Net.Http;
        var url = @"http://www.dsebd.org/displayCompany.php?name=NBL";
        string sourcePage = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(sourcePage);
        HtmlNode specificNode = doc.GetElementById("nodeId");
        HtmlNodeCollection nodesMatchingXPath = specificNode.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("x/path/nodes");
    }
```

Error:

1. 'HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'GetElementById' and no extension method 'GetElementById' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. 'HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'DocumentNode' and no extension method 'DocumentNode' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlNode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What might be the problem?

Comment: Have you put this `using HtmlAgilityPack; ` on top of your cs file and is the library added to the references of your project?

Comment: Yes...I did put... @Sybren

Comment: It seems you are using methods of [Browser.HtmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmldocument%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [Forms.HtmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Take a look at http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/273/using-the-htmlagilitypack-to-parse-html-in-asp-net for methods on how to scrape. Make sure you have the unambiguous way to refer to `HtmlDocument` of HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 0):

> 'HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'GetElementById' and no extension method 'GetElementById' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

you should use 
        doc.GetElement**b**yId() instead of doc.GetElement**B**yId()

> 'HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'DocumentNode' and no extension method 'DocumentNode' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlNode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

i think it can be replaced by

```
      specificNode.OwnerDocument.DocumentNode
```

because they both return `HtmlNodeCollection`

not sure about this though